# Isn't it strange to have branches for totally unrelated code with master?

Tags: git, github, version-control, mercurial, branch

Github does this for .io pages.

A friend of mine worked at a company that had only one repo and 3 branches for backend, ios and android applications.

This seems very strange since the definition of a branch is a state of code that's derived from other state of the code in time. But those are related somehow, that's why we eventually merge.

In those cases seems a bit weird to have branches that are totally unrelated to the repository meaning.

Isn't it?

Comment: Why close? Mind commenting at least?

Comment: they've suggested that any answer would be opinion based, which is sort of the case, but also in another sense not because at least in this instance there's a clear reason why having a single repo for multiple codebases is the wrong approach.

Comment: I agree with two things: This question is primarily opinion-based, and it is indeed strange to use branches in this way. I've never been a big fan of GitHub's `gh-pages`, and your example of three branches for different platforms sounds like a horrible idea. Each of the codebases should (probably) exist in its own repository and any code shared between the repos should (probably) be factored into a library that lives in a fourth repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see why GitHub has chosen that approach, because the gh-pages for a particular repo are intrinsically linked to the codebase for the same repo. They probably have some technical reasons behind the scenes for doing so also. For example, would a separate gh-pages repo be billable against your plan's limit? It'd halve the number of repos you could have in a particular plan.

For three separate codebases though? Nothing short of insanity. It'd create an incredibly messy repository where changes are difficult to keep on top of. When people start creating topic branches it would create more and more mess.  They should be separate repos, without a doubt.